# How many watts total from 1876 Clarendon Dry Pile Battery / Oxford Electric Bell?

Tags: batteries

How many watts has the Clarendon dry pile output since its creation in 1876?

I've tried looking however cannot find any details on this.

Comment: Your units are wrong. You can't have "total watts" over time. You can have "total joules" or "total watt-hours" or "average watts".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some back of the envelope calculations:

Capacitance of the ~2mm radius ball: 200fF

Voltage of (probably) Zamboni piles: 1000V

Charge transferred per oscillation: 2E-10C

Approximate number of rings: 1E10

Total charge transferred: 2C

Approximate energy expended: 2kJ

Also: average rate of charge transfer: 4E-10C/S

Average power: 400nW

Looking at the gap between the bells and clapper, I suspect the voltage is probably lower than 1kV.

Comment: And for comparison, 2kJ is about 5% of the capacity of a common cell-phone battery in 2022, or 15% of the capacity of a single AA.

Comment: Thank Vir you answering that, and the next question is the total joules?

Comment: 2kJ = 2000 Joules

Comment: Thank you all very much.